# What's the difference between get_stylesheet_directory_uri() and get_template_directory_uri() when enqueuing scripts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

It's not a serious question.

I normally use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` when enqueuing scripts in WordPress, which worked fine so far.

I just wonder what's the difference between `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` and `get_template_directory_uri()` when enqueuing scripts in wordpress.

**According to WordPress Codex:**

- `get_template_directory_uri` -> Retrieve template directory URI for the
  current theme.
- `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` ->Retrieve stylesheet directory URI for 
  the current theme/child theme

Then, `get_template_directory_uri` cannot be used for a child theme?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Both functions can be used in a parent or a child theme.

[get_template_directory_uri](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) will always refer to the parent theme folder for assets.

[get_stylesheet_directory_uri](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) will refer to the "current" theme folder for assets (which could be the parent or the child, depending on where it is called).

For example, in a child theme:

```
// This will point to style.css in child theme
wp_enqueue_style( 'my_child_styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css' );

// This will point to style.css in the parent theme
wp_enqueue_style( 'my_parent_styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
```

Note that if a theme is not a child theme, then it is considered a parent theme.

Comment: What conventions? :D :)