# JS file not being loaded in live WordPress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have been successful in loading js files in WordPress many times, and this has me stumped. Here is my current set up for my child theme without success (what is strange is that the googlemaps.js is being loaded properly):

```
function theme_js() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
  '/js/googlemaps.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
  '/js/toggler.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js');
```

I have tried replacing NULL for the array( 'jquery' ) bit to no avail. I am at a loss here. There are many Stack Overflow questions addressing this issue, but most that I have seen have blatant typos or other issues, which I have quadruple checked. (I have included a screenshot of the child theme file structure just for reference) [screenshot of file structure within child theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5D11.png)

Comment: why would script be in stylesheet directory?

Comment: Well that is a good question, I suppose because the other script is loaded properly I figured it would be ok. I guess I shouldn't make that assumption. Going to change to get_template_directory_uri () and see if that is the fix needed.

Comment: That actually didn't work either. I am wondering if it is problematic that I am putting 'theme_js' at the beginning of the wp_enqueue_script variable. I tried changing that to 'toggler_js' but that didn't work...

Comment: And that is precisely the problem. It should absolutely not be 'theme_js' it should be the name of that particular script, it worked once changed to 'toggler'

Comment: @charlietfl Just fyi, the get_stylesheet_directory_uri() is correct, this is a child theme and in order to point to the child theme vs the parent theme it is necessary to use. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797203/whats-the-difference-between-get-stylesheet-directory-uri-and-get-template-di

Answer (score 0):

And that is precisely the problem. It should absolutely not be 'theme_js' it should be the name of that particular script, it worked once changed to 'toggler'

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'toggler', get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/js/toggler.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
```