# I cannot apply JavaScript to WordPress. Can you help me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I followed this tutorial at : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0swZkgTQnk
which explain how to add JavaScript to WordPress. But when I launch the page, in the sourcepage, the .js file is relocated somewhere else.

I put my .js file in "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Websites\www.testsite.dev.cc\wp-content\themes\profile-lite\js" but in the page source, the file is listed in "http://www.testsite.dev.cc/wp-content/themes/profile-lite/style.cssjs/script.js?ver=3.2.1".

I tried to create a folder in "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Websites\www.testsite.dev.cc\wp-content\themes\profile-lite" with the folder "style.cssjs" to see if the file can be read but without any luck!

In my function.php file, here's my code:

```
function cool_scripts(){
    
    wp_enqueue_script('cool-stuff', get_stylesheet_uri(). 'js/script.js', array('jquery'), '3.2.1', false);
}
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','cool_scripts');
```

In my script.js file, here's my code:

```html
//with class div
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $(".videowidth").hover(function(){
                $(this).children("video")[0].play();
            },
            function(){
            $(this).children("video")[0].pause();
            });
        });
        // Without id and class div
        /*$(document).ready(function(){
            $("video").hover(function(){
                $(this)[0].play();
            },
            function(){
            $(this)[0].pause();
            });
        });*/
```

I expect the file to load but I have this error in the console.

(index):103 GET http://www.testsite.dev.cc/wp-content/themes/profile-lite/style.cssjs/script.js?ver=3.2.1 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9FPg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_stylesheet_uri()`.

```
function cool_scripts(){

    wp_enqueue_script('cool-stuff', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). 'js/script.js', array('jquery'), '3.2.1', false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','cool_scripts');
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797203/whats-the-difference-between-get-stylesheet-directory-uri-and-get-template-di) for more information about wether to choose `get_template_directory_uri` or `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't saw that he used get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead of get_stylesheet_uri(). I will go look at your link you provided. But now i got another  error on my console wich says "script.js?ver=3.2.1:3 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function". Precisely on that line of code : "   $(".videowidth").hover(function(){
". Ive read online that sometimes you have to replace $ with jQuery to make it work. Is that true?

Comment: Because its working on a HTML file when i put my script inthe body. Want i want to achieve is to play a video when i mouse over an icon. I tested it like said on a HTML file but when i test it on wordpress, it dosen't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found it!!

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('video').hover(function() {
            this.play();
        }, function() {
            this.pause()
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```